# LUIS buitin datetime.v2 entity unable to parse daterange type of values

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have used pre-built datetime.v2 entity to handle all my datetime related stuff in LUIS.

**I have this utterance: `March to June 2017`**

The expected output from LUIS should be, in the entities:

```
"resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "XXXX-03",
            "type": "daterange",
            "start": "2017-03-01",
            "end": "2017-06-01"
          }
        ]
      }
```

---

But this is what I am getting when I query LUIS:

```
{
  "query": "march to june 2017",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "TestIntent",
    "score": 1.0
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "TestIntent",
      "score": 1.0
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.05487651
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "march",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
      "startIndex": 0,
      "endIndex": 4,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "XXXX-03",
            "type": "daterange",
            "start": "2017-03-01",
            "end": "2017-04-01"
          },
          {
            "timex": "XXXX-03",
            "type": "daterange",
            "start": "2018-03-01",
            "end": "2018-04-01"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "entity": "june 2017",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
      "startIndex": 9,
      "endIndex": 17,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "2017-06",
            "type": "daterange",
            "start": "2017-06-01",
            "end": "2017-07-01"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

I have written the following C# code, to query the date range in my LUIS intent

```
        [LuisIntent("TestIntent")]
        public async Task TestIntentHandler(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            EntityRecommendation dateTimeEntity, dateRangeEntity;
            if(result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetimeV2.date", out dateTimeEntity))
            {
               var s = dateTimeEntity.Resolution.Values.Select(x => x).OfType<List<object>>().SelectMany(i => i).ToList();
            }
            if(result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetimeV2.daterange", out dateRangeEntity))
            {
                var s = dateRangeEntity.Resolution.Values.Select(x => x).OfType<List<object>>().SelectMany(i => i).FirstOrDefault();
                var type = s.GetType();
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how to query the range of months like the above utterance in LUIS using the prebuilt datetime.v2 type of entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on my side, but in my opinion, March (3/1 to 3/31) is date range and June (6/1 to 6/30) is date range, which is easy to be recognized as two date range (as LUIS did). In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities#builtindatetimev2), it gives us an example date range ***may 2nd to may 5th***, if possible, please specify the day of start month and end month, such as ***March 1st to June 1st 2017***.

[image]

Besides, I checked the source of `TryFindEntity`, and I find it assign **null** or **FirstOrDefault** entity to `EntityRecommendation entity`, so your `dateRangeEntity` will be the first entity even though LUIS return two entities (**march** and **june 2017**). If you want to extract two entities when you query `march to june 2017`, please operate `LuisResult result` directly, not call `TryFindEntity` method.

*Source code of `TryFindEntity`*:

```
// Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions
public static bool TryFindEntity(this LuisResult result, string type, out EntityRecommendation entity)
{
    IList<EntityRecommendation> expr_14 = result.Entities;
    entity = ((expr_14 != null) ? expr_14.FirstOrDefault((EntityRecommendation e) => e.Type == type) : null);
    return entity != null;
}
```